# Trying to add a highlight on mouse-over for dropdown menu selections in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I'd like add a mouse-over highlight in my dropdown menu selections since currently on my menus i only have a simple dropdown. I have the newest wordpress version and I'm working on oneengine theme. I've tried to add this from some suggestions i have found on google but it didn't work at all with the mouse-over having no reaction at all:

```
#navigation li:hover a {
  background-color:#012A5E;
  color:#F1F1F1;
}
```

And here is the code related to the menu itself from my style.css:

```
#main-menu-top ul.sub-menu li a:hover, 
#main-menu-top ul.sub-menu li a:active {
border-left-color:#ccc; border-bottom-color: transparent;
 }
#main-menu-top .sub-menu {
 float: left; position: 
 absolute; display:
 none; padding: 0; 
 text-align: center; 
 border: 1px solid #BDC3C7; 
 border-top: none; 
 background: black; 
 z-index: 9999;
}
#main-menu-top li:hover ul.sub-menu {
display: block;
 }
 #main-menu-top .sub-menu li {
display: block; min-width: 100px;
}
 #main-menu-top .sub-menu li a { padding: 10px 15px;
 }
}
```

Also does this change require changing the style.css only or do i have to make a j.script code aswell? Any kind of help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [this](http://demo.enginethemes.com/oneengine/) theme? If yes, try using `nav ul li:hover { background: red;}`.

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed Thanks, but where should i insert this?

Comment: Does your theme have a custom css page?

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed Ok, I've found it, I inserted the code you gave me in the custom CSS and it works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed on a side note, since you've already helped me could I ask you one more question regarding submenus? I'd like to add additional submenu to some of the selections with the existing code. Like, if i go to menu1 it has menuA and menuB dropped down and when i hover over menuA two other menus menuX and menuY show up.

Comment: Refer this please: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-sub-menu

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed The problem is that if i just add the sub-sub menu it doesn't work. I'ts the same thing with the clean oneengine theme -> if i add submenu it appears glitched on main menu. Should i just copy the code i gave here from stylesheet and change the "sub-menu" to "sub-sub-menu" or something?

Comment: I didn't get you.. :(

Comment: @ArshadMuhammed Sorry my english is bad i'll try to explain differently. Default oneengine theme doesn't support submenus or even links that are not #"link". I had to add everything that i posted here to stylesheet. I figured it would be easier if you can see for yourself, go to [link](http://www.dobry-klimat.com/) and hover the mouse over "OFERTA", "usługi kominiarskie" was supposed to be a sub-submenu to the "kominek tradycyjny" in this example but it's glitched.

Comment: Sorry bro.. No time now.. will catch u later.. sory..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your theme have a custom css page? If yes then add this code there.
`nav ul li:hover { background: red;}`
If it is not available then go to Dashboard->Appearance->Editor and select 'Stylesheet (style.css)' file and add the code to the end of the file. But this has a problen. In the future when you update the theme there is a chance of losing all your edits. So it is safe to create a child theme in order to keep all the changes permanently. See [this link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to know more about child themes.